# USB HID Device Driver Development in FreeBSD

Tags: c, linux-device-driver, freebsd, device-driver, hid

I am currently developing a driver for an HID device on a **FreeBSD system**. The idea is that the driver writes to the device's registers through the Control Endpoint. From then on the device acts according to the data fed.

Since I have just started out on drivers, I am following a guide book (I would name it here but I don't know if I can? ). This book tackles a **USB ULPT (Printer) driver**, explaining the basic driver for a **USB device**. However when I am trying to implement these concepts to the **HID device**, I am having trouble, more specifically when it comes to identifying and probing the device.

Since I haven't found much material online, I was wondering are there any guides/books or tutorials I can follow which tackle the development of an HID device driver on **FreeBSD** or at least **Linux systems**. A pointer (pun intended) to the right direction would be enough to get me going again.

Comment: Is this a USB-HID device, as in, it serves up HID report descriptors and reports according to the USB standard? Or is this a generic USB device, and you'd like to write a driver which makes it behave like a HID device to FreeBSD? In the former case, you probably can start your driver at a higher level - the descriptor/report parsing should be reusable. (I'm not a FreeBSD expert unfortunately, but have done HID stuff on OS X and Linux.)

Comment: It is a standard HID device. I am currently using the generic uhid driver which comes with FreeBSD, both for research and to aid me in the development of the specific driver I'm writing. Right now I'm in the process of writing an application to be able to communicate with the device.

Comment: Are you sure you need a kernel driver? For exampe, I've [written](https://rsmith.home.xs4all.nl/hardware/setting-the-razer-ornata-chroma-color-from-userspace.html) about changing keyboard colors from userspace using `libusb` and Python.